# Photoshop CS6: create looped animation from layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, animation, video

A client sent us a .MP4 video, made of 10 frames and text, which loop 3 times.

Since we need to edit the text (translate it into another language), the client sent us a .PSD source file, also containing 10 frames / layers.

We assumed we would need to work with Photoshop CS6 to edit the text (since the source file is a .PSD, see above).

However, when we try to render the video as .MP4, there is no loop.

Is there a particular option to check to preserve a loop when saving a file with Photoshop CS6?

Is Photoshop CS6 at least the right tool for the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the animation from Photoshop as a .gif file, there are two places you can set the number of loops. One is in the Timeline window itself:

[image]

The other is when you use the "Save for Web" command, and save the file as a .gif animation. Near the bottom right is the "Looping Options" dropdown, where you can choose "Other" to select the number of times you want the animation to loop (if you had set "3 times" in the Timeline window, this setting will already be set to (3) as you see here, but you can choose any number you want in this area).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no "save for web as an MP4" option in Photoshop. So your question is unclear.

You can render the video, then use video software to duplicate it two more times and render again to a single file. (Premier, After Effects, as well as tons of shareware out there.)

You can duplicate the animation two more times in Photoshop then render the video. That way you render the video with 3 cycles.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question and removed "save for web as an MP4". We already tried the second option you suggest, but we only have one loop, not three, even when we duplicate the animation. Is this normal?

Comment: Well you have to either duplicate the timeline or frames in the Timeline Panel. You can't just duplicate layers.

Answer (score -1):

You can just copy the layers a couple of times untin its long enough and then create the .mp4 using all the layers. On this way you make the video a long as you want :)